# Concatenation of files using ffmpeg does not work as I expected. Why?

Tags: file, ffmpeg, concatenation, mpeg

I execute the following command line

```
ffmpeg.exe
    -i C:\Beema\video-source\DO_U_BEEMA176x144short.avi 
    -i C:\Beema\video-source\DO_U_BEEMA176x144short.avi 
    -i C:\Beema\temp\9016730-51056331-stitcheds.avi  
    -i C:\Beema\video-source\GOTTA_BEEMA176x144short.avi 
    -y -ac 1 -r 24 -b 25K 
    C:\Beema\video-out\9a062fb6-d448-48fe-b006-a85d51adf8a1.mpg
```

The output file in video-out ends up having a single copy of DO_U_BEEMA.  I do not understand why ffmpeg is not concatenating.

Any help is dramatically appreciated,

Answer (score 2):

```
mencoder -oac copy -ovc copy file1 file2 file3 … -o final_movie.mpg
```

Have you tried with mencoder?

Also are all of the files the same bitrate and dimensions?  If not your going to need to make sure all of the video files are identical in these two areas before attempting to combine.  It also appears your attempting to combine .avi's with a single .mpg, you'll most likely want to convert the .mpg to a similar format when re-encoding.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If it has C:\, it's Windows. use:
copy video1 + video2 + video3
and add more + videoN instances until you get there.

Comment: Does that concatenate video (re-encoding as needed and such) or just naïvely concatenate files?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the command that will work for you first cat the files then pipe to ffmpeg

cat C:\Beema\video-source\DO_U_BEEMA176x144short.avi C:\Beema\video-source\DO_U_BEEMA176x144short.avi C:\Beema\temp\9016730-51056331-stitcheds.avi
C:\Beema\video-source\GOTTA_BEEMA176x144short.avi | ffmpeg -f mpeg -i -  C:\Beema\video-out\9a062fb6-d448-48fe-b006-a85d51adf8a1.mpg

-i - is important "-" this is the piped input to ffmpeg

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I guess `ffmpeg` cann't do that. It usually takes only one input file. Trying to `cat` files to input may result in a lump togather, but i guess it won't stitch properly.

Best bet is `mencoder` or using `transcode`